# Run MQSC Command via SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.EVENT

Tags: ibm-mq

I have connected remotely to a QMgr via MQ Explorer on Windows. The MQ server version is 7.5.0.1. I can put messages in `SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.EVENT` from MQ Explorer successfully and when I dump `SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.EVENT`, I can see my messages. As long as I know, I should be able to run PCF commands and MQSC commands via this channel. So, I put `DISPLAY QMGR ALL` message inside this queue and I can successfully see this message on MQ Server. My question is how can I run this message remotely via this channel? Thanks.

[image]

IBM Doc indicates that I should be able to receive the command result in `SYSTEM.MQSC.REPLY.QUEUE`. But I can not browse this queue from client MQ Explorer. The queue type for this queue is `Model`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of problems here.

First, you are using the wrong queue.  The command server listens on `SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE`.  The queue to which you are sending messages, `SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.EVENT` is the queue to which the QMgr puts event messages after executing commands, provided of course that command events are enabled.

The second problem, as Jason mentions, is that the `runmqsc` processor takes human-readable script and converts it into commands the QMgr can understand.  Passing textual commands directly to the command server won't work.

Typically we do what you want by passing the commands to runmqsc directly such as...

```
echo DISPLAY QMGR ALL | runmqsc MYQMGRNAME
```

If you require the ability to do this as a client, then you want to either download [SupportPac MO72](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMO72), or head over to MQ Gem and pick up a copy of [MQSCX](http://mqgem.com/mqscx.html).  Either of these will accept the command above on a local queue manager, and both can also be supplied with MQ Channel params and connect to a remote QMgr.

In addition to this basic functionality, the MQSCX product also has its own internal script parsing and execution.  Suppose, for instance, that you want to do something depending on the command level of the QMgr.

Using `runmqsc` you could issue the command above, filter the resulting 2-column output through `grep`, `awk`, or similar, then capture the final output into a variable.  You might need to do this multiple times to capture multiple values, invoking a new `runmqsc` each time and parsing the output in your script.  You must then generate the string for the actual command you wanted to run when you started all this, and pass it to another invocation of `runmqsc`.

Alternatively, MQSCX lets you issue the `DISPLAY` command, then reference the resulting values directly by name.  For example, you can pass MQSCX a couple lines of script telling it to inquire on the QMgr and then take a conditional action based on the command version, all without ever having to drop back into shell, bat or Perl script.

*Full disclosure, I do not work for or get a commission from MQ Gem.  I just don't like to beat my head against the wall writing 100 lines of code where 2 will do.  If you do any amount of MQSC scripting, the ROI on MQSCX is measured in minutes.  And it happens to be 100% on-topic as an answer to this question.*

Comment: Just wow! your knowledge in MQ is unbelievable. Thank you again T.Rob.

Comment: I have successfully run MQSC command remotely via MO72. However, I have a question, is it possible to run OS command remotely via MQ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, if the ID is an administrator. Sadly, this feature cannot be disabled so anyone who can escalate to admin rights can execute commands on the underlying host with the MQ service account.  Basically, you define either a Process to trigger, or else a service object.  Either of these will execute commands in the OS. They are not designed to do this so you have to define a new process or service for each command, then delete it if you don't need it again.

Comment: Ok, In order to run OS commands I run this command remotely: DEFINE SERVICE('myservice') STARTCMD('ping 127.0.0.1') and it successfully created. Now I want to start that service, so I run this command: START SERVICE('myservice'), but I got AMQ8734- Command failed - programm could not be started. My ID is administrator. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Here's the thing... if some future person wants to know the same thing, how would they know to look for that in this question's comments?  You are now in territory where you need to open a new question. The good news is that as a new question you can include formatted code so you can show the object description that you defined.

Comment: You're right. I will ask this in a new question and I am sure you are the one who will answer it ;) thanks

Answer (score 3):

The command server doesnt process textual messages, it processes PCF messages. You need to build a message in PCF format and it can be processed. See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.adm.doc/q019980_.htm

Ideally you would use real PCF format but there is a PCF format where you can send MQSC commands ('escaped' PCF - see here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q087230_.htm?lang=en)

Comment: Thanks JasonE, I read the docs, the problem is there was no example in IBM documents about this, would you please give me an example in escape commands?